# az ssh - could not find ssh-keygen.exe

Tags: azure, ssh

Can anyone please help me to figure out "SSH connection" issue with AZ Azure. I have **AZ-CLI 2.29.0** installed on my windows 7 PC.
When I am trying to SSH with following command -

```
az ssh vm --ip MY_VM_IP
```

It is throwing following error -

> ERROR: Could not find ssh-keygen.exe.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

I searched about the error and found that if I already have **GIT** installed then I should try the same command in **GIT-BASH** but the solution didn't work.

However the command "ssh-keygen" is working fine in my **GIT-BASH**

Thank you!!

Comment: Please refer this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/77957

Comment: Thank you for your response, FYI, I am using windows 7.